# Read serialized file, record by record

Tags: php

I save to file data from form:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$url = $_POST['url'];
$comm = $_POST['comm'];

$data["name"]=$name;
$data["url"]=$url;
$data["comm"]=$comm;

file_put_contents("db.txt", serialize($data));
```

Now, I would like to read this file record by record.

```
 $file_handle = fopen("db.txt", "r");
    while (!feof($file_handle)) {

        $line = fgets($file_handle);
        $arr = unserialize($line);

        var_dump($arr);
    }
    fclose($file_handle);
```

But this code read only last record. How to read all file?

Comment: What do you mean by `record by record`? Are you sure that there more than one `record`?

Comment: My mistake, I just saw that the code always overwrites the file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `file_put_contents("db.txt", serialize($data));` to

```
file_put_contents("db.txt",  PHP_EOL .serialize($data), FILE_APPEND);
```

file_put_contents("db.txt", serialize($data));// will over write the file again and again. so you cant able to read all the data. FILE_APPEND helps to append the data And PHP_EOL helps to leave a line breake.

Answer (score 1):

Hi i try this code for your solution:

```
<?php
    $name = "rdn";
    $url = "http://google.it";
    $comm = "com";

    $data["name"]=$name;
    $data["url"]=$url;
    $data["comm"]=$comm;

file_put_contents("db.txt", serialize($data)."\n",FILE_APPEND); 

$fh = fopen('db.txt','r');
while ($line = fgets($fh)) {


  // <... Do your work with the line ...>
   var_dump(unserialize($line));
}
fclose($fh);


?>
```

without **"\n"** don't work!